# Ember Promises missing finally handler?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

The ember documentation states that there is a `finally` handler available on Promises:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html#method_finally

However, using `finally` on a promise yields `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` (http://jsfiddle.net/XawmE/).

Is the Ember documentation wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're accidentally using the native `Promise`, not `Ember`'s :-)

See this fiddle to use the correct promises: http://jsfiddle.net/XawmE/1/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve(1).finally(function(){
    console.log('finally');
});
```

For easier usage, you can do:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});
var Promise = Ember.RSVP.Promise;

Promise.resolve(1).finally(function(){
    console.log('finally');
});
```